# Reducing count value to repeat a loop cycle is not working. The for loop in python has an exception handler that has a continue statement

Tags: python, exception, continue

```
for i in range(0, 650):
    s = ticket[i]
    try:
        response = resource.get(path='ticket/%s' % s[0]) # Get ticket data from RT server
    except urllib2.URLError, e: # If connection fails
        resource = RTResource(url, user, pwd, CookieAuthenticator) # Reconnect to RT server
        count -= 1 # Count re-connection attempts
        if count < 0:
            print "Connection failed at ticket %s" % s[0]
            print "Got %s tickets out of %s" % {i + 1, len(ticket) + 1}
            wb.save(fname)
            sys.exit(1)
        print 'Trying again...'
        i -= 1
        continue
    count = 10
    ...more code here...
```

The above code executes well but will skip an iteration when exception is thrown. I am trying to decrement the value of i and then continuing the loop so that when exception is thrown, the loop will repeat for same value of i. When a value of i is skipped I lose one ticket from RT server. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ... can't do that in python.  You can't affect the value of the iterator - it's using it's own internal value for each step in the loop, not paying attention to your attempts to override.  If you *have* to succeed for each iteration I use something like this:

```
while True:
    # code here
    if success:
        break
```

And place that inside your `for` loop.  Or better, extract a method to simplify readability, but that's another post.

Comment: changed from for loop to while loop. Should work. Can't test it though. Will wait for a Connection  error to verify.

Answer (score 2):

(Besides the correct point raised by g.d.d.c. about the inability to decrement the loop counter the specific way you've gone, )this sort of stuff is exactly the motivation for [`finally`](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-341.html). You should probably organize your code as follows:

- `try` - the part that's supposed to run but might not
- `except` - the part to do only if there was a problem
- `else` (optional) - the part to do only if there wasn't a problem
- `finally` - stuff to do in any case

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to embedding a while loop in your for loop, as suggested by g.d.d.c, is to simply use a while loop instead of a for loop, like so:

```
i = 0
while i < 650:
    s = ticket[i]
    try:
        response = resource.get(path='ticket/%s' % s[0]) # Get ticket data from RT server
    except urllib2.URLError, e: # If connection fails
        resource = RTResource(url, user, pwd, CookieAuthenticator) # Reconnect to RT server
        count -= 1 # Count re-connection attempts
        if count < 0:
            print "Connection failed at ticket %s" % s[0]
            print "Got %s tickets out of %s" % {i + 1, len(ticket) + 1}
            wb.save(fname)
            sys.exit(1)
        print 'Trying again...'
        continue
    count = 10
    i += 1
    ...more code here...
```

Comment: Thanks
That's exactly what I did